# Deriving a cannonical structure for a record in coq (ssreflect)

Tags: coq, ssreflect

Given the following assumptions:

```
Variable A : finType.
Variable B : finType.
Variable C : finType.
```

and a record defined as:

```
Record example := Example {
       example_A : A;
       example_B : B;
       example_C : C;
}.
```

Intuitively, it would seem that example would also have to be of `finType`.

Looking at other code-bases, I have seen people derive `finType` for records with only one non-proof term using a construction of the form

```
Definition <record>_subType := Eval hnf in [subtype for <record-accessor>].
Definition <record>_finMixin := Eval hnf in [finMixin of <record> by <:].
```

But in this case, there are multiple fields to the record.

**Is there an automatic way to derive fintype for the record, if not, how can fintype be derived for the record?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many interface implementations in mathematical components can be derived by showing that your type is a retract of some other type that implements that interface.  In your example, we just have to convert the record to a tuple.

```
From mathcomp Require Import
  ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool ssrnat eqtype seq choice fintype.

Variables A B C : finType.

Record example := Example {
  example_A : A;
  example_B : B;
  example_C : C
}.

Definition prod_of_example e :=
  let: Example a b c := e in (a, b, c).

Definition example_of_prod p :=
  let: (a, b, c) := p in Example a b c.

Lemma prod_of_exampleK : cancel prod_of_example example_of_prod.
Proof. by case. Qed.

Definition example_eqMixin :=
  CanEqMixin prod_of_exampleK.
Canonical example_eqType :=
  Eval hnf in EqType example example_eqMixin.
Definition example_choiceMixin :=
  CanChoiceMixin prod_of_exampleK.
Canonical example_choiceType :=
  Eval hnf in ChoiceType example example_choiceMixin.
Definition example_countMixin :=
  CanCountMixin prod_of_exampleK.
Canonical example_countType :=
  Eval hnf in CountType example example_countMixin.
Definition example_finMixin :=
  CanFinMixin prod_of_exampleK.
Canonical example_finType :=
  Eval hnf in FinType example example_finMixin.
```

At the end of this snippet, `example` is declared as a `finType`. (Note that all the other declarations of `eqType`, `choiceType`, etc, are also necessary, since `finType` is a subclass of those.)